# Get Running Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

if i run various threads by code

```
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ca)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ca.Message);
            }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Name = "Thread1";
        t.Start()
```

can we have something that we can later on terminate the thread by knowing its name lets say we intend to stop thread1 or thread4 we should be able to stop it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things will be quite easy if you have something like a `Dictionary<string,Thread>`, when you start a thread, put it in the dictionary with its name as the key. Then you can get some thread by its name using:

```
var t = threads["thread1"];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads
```

Or it's simpler if you have a list of threads and whenever you create a new one, you add it to your list, and you regularly remove threads that have exited. You might also need synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

The [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkb1k2x8.aspx) class has an [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) method which allows you to terminate the thread. This being said the proper way to terminate a thread is to use some a shared resource which indicates whether the thread should continue or stop. For example inside the thread you could implement a mechanism which tests the value of this static variable in a loop and break out of the loop. On the main thread when you decide to terminate the background thread simply set the value of the static variable and the thread will simply stop by itself.

Here's an example:

```
 private static volatile bool _shouldTerminate = false;
```

and inside the thread:

```
while (!_shouldTerminate)
{
    // .. do something useful
}
```

and when you decide to stop the thread from another thread:

```
_shouldTerminate = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build a `Dictionary <string,Thread>` . The key is the name and the value is the thread object itself. You then call Abort method on the thread object obtained from the dicitonary.

NOTE: Abort is not a very good way to end a thread. Try using some global flags.

Comment: Global Flags? i need to interrupt the thread and order that thread "stop mister where ever you are" :)

Comment: @Afnan: Global flags, as in class fields that are visible in the method that runs on the worker thread.

Comment: @Afnan: There is no way to absolutely instantly stop a thread. `Abort()` might do it but usually there is a slight delay. If you use flags you must query their state. If you want to stop the thread relatively instantly then you would have to query that flag after each instruction which might not be desirable. So you have to crefully design the code that runs on the thread and the code that uses the thread result to take these facts into account.